# How to add a scroll view in an Android app

Tags: java, android

I want to add scroll in my XML without editing the following code. Is there any way of adding it in the following XML? I tried by adding Scroll view and then linear view but it makes the view cut. Is there any way of making it better, I have searched other repository but I didn't find a solution.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Activity.BookSeatsActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="12"
        >
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/wheel"
                    android:src="@drawable/mywheel"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    />


                <GridView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/grid"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/wheel"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:numColumns="5"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".4"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".6"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:src="@drawable/seat_open"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Available"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:src="@drawable/seat_booked"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"
                    android:text="Unavailable"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:src="@drawable/seat_selected"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Selected"/>

            </LinearLayout>




        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            >


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Seat Selected :  "
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_seat_selected"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                />


        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <Button

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bt_booking_details"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="Enter Booking Details"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                android:background="@drawable/circular_button"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code snippet for the XML file and change the image view as per your needs.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="12"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="5">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/wheel"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/sports" />


                    <GridView
                        android:id="@+id/grid"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/wheel"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:numColumns="5"
                        android:padding="1dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".4" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_weight=".6"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:src="@drawable/toys" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="Available" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:src="@drawable/mobile" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="Unavailable" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:src="@drawable/home" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="Selected" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Seat Selected :  "
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_seat_selected"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_booking_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="Enter Booking Details"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have added androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView but it makes my app crash

Comment: I think you didn't migrate the project to AndroidX. Please use NestedScrollView alone

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code, I just changed the scroll view to be match_parent for width and height and the linear layout to be match_parent for width&  wrap_content for height.
Please note that this view won't scroll till you run it on a small screen device.
and please change the images as you need.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="12">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/wheel"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    />


                <GridView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/grid"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/wheel"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:numColumns="5"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".4"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".6"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Available"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"
                    android:text="Unavailable"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Selected"/>

            </LinearLayout>




        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            >


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Seat Selected :  "
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_seat_selected"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                />


        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <Button

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bt_booking_details"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="Enter Booking Details"

                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```